# Medication for cat with difficulty breathing / congestion

Tags: cats, upper-respiratory-disease

I'm watching a friend's cat and she has trouble breathing, sounding like she's snoring/slurping constantly ("nasal stertor").

Apparently this is "normal" for her.  She's always been like this, and she behaves normally otherwise, but it would be nice if there were some way to improve the symptoms.

She's had surgery for nasopharyngeal polyp(s?) and antibiotics to clear infections.  Her nose is constantly plugged with grayish mucus and she breathes through her mouth.

Expectorant like Bisolvon or Guaifenesin?

Comment: ask a vet before you give any type of medication to a cat,and please make sure to get the cat to a vet to find if there is any physological problems,polyps might reapear,there is several things that might cause breathing problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had a cat who had this problem and my vet advised using [saline nasal drops](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G7QWZ8) to help clear the mucous (you drip in a drop or two, then let her sneeze everything out, it can be a mess).

This cat was extremely docile and would let me do anything to him. Once I was clipping his claws and accidentally cut the quick (so he started bleeding). I told him to stay put while I ran to the kitchen for flour, and he just laid there on his back until I got back.

MOST cats are difficult to give nasal drops to. Honestly I wouldn't advise it for a cat that is not yours. You can suggest it to your friend, but it sounds like they're already working with their vet.